# Что возвращает getElementById и где посмотреть возвращённое значение

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, dom

Помогите решить проблему. Изучаю javascriprt, перешёл к методу getElementById поиск элемента по его id, в книге также написано то, что текст найденного элемента можно изменить, присвоив к переменной, в которую возвращён элемент, значение innerHTML.

В итоге, что бы я не делал, у меня текст в элементе не менялся. Тогда я решил вывести в документ значение, которое возвращает переменной метод getElementById. Оказалось, значение переменной после возврата null. Фрагмент кода ниже.

**Вопрос**:

правильно ли, что getElementById возвращает null? Если нет, то какое значение он должен возвратить с учётом моего примера?

Фрагмент кода:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var q = document.getElementById('abz');
q.innerHTML = 'возврат getElementById';
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1 id="abz"> ПРИВЕТСТВИЕ </h1>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(q);
</script>
</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должен возвращать null, так как ваш скрипт выполняется до загрузки документа, решения (все или):

- поставьте скрипт в конец body
- обрабатывайте в window.onload
- [реализуйте document.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/815386) и обрабатывайте в нем.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, сейчас буду разбираться в сказанном Вами.
Всё получилось!